# Is there OnLoad event for C# libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I want to initialize my C# library as it loads by another process, is it possible and if so - how?

Comment: The CLR does apparently support this, but the compiler does not - see [Module initializers in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915506/module-initializers-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Instead, you can add a static constructor to your class, which will execute the first time that the class is used.

Comment: "execute the first time"... make that "execute *before* the first time *any other member is accessed* ".

Comment: because it depends on a class rather than the DLL itself, which is fine and working, but not perfect, not as it suppose to work.