# Automatically run code on referenced assembly during startup?? What is this called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In .NET, there is something that can automatically run a piece of code in a referenced assembly when the assembly is loaded.

For example, you can have a class decorated with a sort of attribute that lives in project Foo(A Class Library). And project Bar(A Web App) simply references project Foo. When Bar loads, that decorated code in Foo gets run somehow. I believe this is a newer feature.

Can someone tell what this feature is called??

**Update:** Thanks Shiva! Not Module Initialize. Although it lead me to the right answer. [PreApplicationStartMethod and it's supported in .NET!](http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/08/27/initialize-assemblies-using-preapplicationstartmethodattribute-aspnet4-app/) Thanks all!!

Comment: How do you believe such feature exist? Any reference?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. I've come across it twice in the last year and thought it was really cool. Now for the life of me I can't recall or google this.

Comment: but are you sure this exist? I don't think so it exit(atleast in c#). I did some research some time back. Can't get anything.

Comment: Be ware -  this can cause problems with loader locks. I think that may be part of the reason it is not widely supported. You are better off writing some simple reflection code to look for a class with an attribute and instantiate that in a model similar to what the nunit framework does.

Comment: Found it! PreApplicationStartMethod! Thanks all!

Comment: Good to read you've found it, you might want to add it as an answer so we can vote for it.

Comment: Since it turns out this was actually an ASP.NET question and that the answer was not module initializers I'm voting to reopen this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out I was looking for [PreApplicationStartMethod](http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/08/27/initialize-assemblies-using-preapplicationstartmethodattribute-aspnet4-app/)! Thanks all!

Comment: If this is specific for ASP.NET then I'll suggest you to add appropriate tag and some text in your question. That will hep google to find this page(is what I believe).

Comment: The link for PreApplicationStartMethod above no longer exists. However, a simple google search will yield some good results.

Answer (score 3):

Do you, by chance, mean Module Initializer? They are capable of things you describe, but it seems that they are not supported in C#. They are a part of CLR yes, but not a part of C# language itself.

Some links with further information and research:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/11/19/494914.aspx

[Module initializers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915506/module-initializers-in-c-sharp)

[.Net: Running code when assembly is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505237/net-running-code-when-assembly-is-loaded) - thanks to **J...** for pointing out this link

Comment: This is basically Hans's answer from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505237/net-running-code-when-assembly-is-loaded

Comment: Turns out I was looking for PreApplicationStartMethod! Thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

You might have also have a look at [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody/). Fody is "an Extensible tool for weaving .net assemblies" which you can install as a nuget package. There is an add-in for fody called [Module Initializers](https://github.com/fody/moduleinit). Which under the hood uses the, in other answers already mentioned [module initializers](http://einaregilsson.com/module-initializers-in-csharp/), but takes away the plumping.

From the documentation:

What it does:
Finds a class, in the target assembly, named `ModuleInitializer` with the following form:

```
public static class ModuleInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        //Init code
    }
}
```

It then Injects the following code into the module initializer of the target assembly. This code will be called when the assembly is loaded into memory

```
static <Module>()
{
    ModuleInitializer.Initialize();
}
```

Comment: Turns out I was looking for PreApplicationStartMethod! Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

If am not wrong then you're looking for "Module Initializer".
Check [this](http://einaregilsson.com/module-initializers-in-csharp/) out

Comment: Turns out I was looking for PreApplicationStartMethod! Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [Module Initializers](http://einaregilsson.com/module-initializers-in-csharp/)?

Comment: Turns out I was looking for PreApplicationStartMethod! Thanks though!